# Will the Sun's orbit around the Milky Way degrade once it transitions to a white dwarf with half its original mass?

Tags: orbital-motion, sun, milky-way

Does the Sun's mass factor in at all when it comes to its orbit around the Milky Way, such that if it lost half its mass, its orbit would change? Or is it a matter of the center of the Milky Way being so relatively massive that virtually no mass change in the Sun would affect its orbit?

Answer (score 4):

The gravitational acceleration that a body feels is independent of its mass.

If the Sun loses half its mass, then it feels half the gravitational force due to the same gravitational potential and therefore experiences an unchanged acceleration.

If the acceleration is the same then so will be the orbit.

In actual fact, the orbit of the Sun is likely to be changed significantly over the course of billions of years not by its mass loss, but due to encounters with spiral density waves and giant molecular clouds.